# Not able to set storage of GSM modem using AT command AT+CPMS

Tags: serial-port, at-command, gsmcomm

I am trying to set the memory location of my phone (Nokia 2730 Classic) but I am not able to set the storage location. I have also tried with the 7 port multi sim card hub and got same issue there as well. I am using the Ubuntu system and using Minicom and Screen command to connect serial port. When I tried to send SMS from the device using AT command it is working fine but the reading of SMS is not working due to storage location is not set.

While I am trying to execute command AT+CPMS I got below results.

```
AT+CPMS?                                                                        
+CPMS: ,,,,,,,,                                                                 

OK            

AT+CPMS=?                                                                       
+CPMS: (),(),()                                                                 

OK
```

And when I try to set the location of storage using below commands then getting errors.

```
AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM"                                                          
ERROR                                                                           
AT+CPMS="ME","ME","ME"                                                          
ERROR                                                                           
AT+CPMS="MT","MT","MT"                                                          
ERROR                                                                           
AT+CPMS="SM","ME","MT"                                                          
ERROR
```

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks

Comment: It seems a bug a bug of your device. Are you sure that it communicates correcly with the SIM card?

Comment: For example: is the PIN correctly inserted?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni yes it is communicating with the sim. I am able to send SMS through AT command but while I am trying to read SMS it gives the error. So I checked the storage preference and while I run AT+CPMS at that time it shows output like above and if I am trying to set AT+CPMS="SM" then also it's giving an error.